# BackupPC - No website Access after installation

Tags: software-installation, gui, backuppc

I have installed backuppc from the repositories. I confirmed to use Apache and noted the random password for the GUI user. There was no install error.
When I tried to login to

```
http://myhost.mydomain/backuppc
```

I did get a password box but after the password box there was not the BackupPC GUI but a popup window

```
 You have chosen to open:

 which is: BIN file (6.1 KB)
 from: http://myhost.mydomain
 Would you like to save this file?
```

I had a running apache2 on the server. I am not sure how the installer gets its page included into Apache. I just saw and `/etc/backuppc/pc/apache.conf` file, but did not understand what it does. There is cgi content in `/usr/share/backuppc/cgi-bin`, but it does not seem to be available to Apache.

I did try the install on a other machine, also Xubunut16.04, but I had the same result.

Any ideas?
Thanks
CatMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here under Ubuntu server 16.04.2 amd64
Installed by apt-get install backuppc

My solution was

```
sudo a2disconf serve-cgi-bin  
sudo service apache2 reload
```

empty cache every time you make a change

source:

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/BackupPC/

Comment: Thanks. Got it working with that. The link is very useful, since it has also a hint for another potential troubleshooting issue.